# Density of states does not scale properly with supercell

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, density-of-states, supercell

I am performing some DFT calculations of monolayer hexagonal boron nitride in Quantum ESPRESSO. I have been trying to calculate the density of states of a 7 x 7 supercell of h-BN, but the resulting density of states does not scale up properly. For a 1 x 1 primitive cell system, I get a smooth plot; for a 3 x 3 system, I get an identical plot, but for a 7 x7 system, there is too much noise:

[image]
[image]
[image]

What might be the cause of this trouble? The only difference between the scf and nscf files for the supercells is the number of K-POINTS and total number of atoms.

scf file for 1 x 1:

```
&CONTROL
  calculation = 'scf'
  prefix = 'hbn'
  pseudo_dir = '../pseudos/'
  outdir = '../out/'
/

&SYSTEM
  ibrav = 0
  nat = 2
  ntyp = 2
  occupations = 'smearing'
  smearing = 'mv'
  degauss =   0.002
  ecutwfc =   60
  ecutrho =   600
/

&ELECTRONS
  mixing_beta =   0.7
  conv_thr =      1d-6
/
ATOMIC_SPECIES
    B      10.811       B.pbe-n-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
    N      14.0067      N.pbe-n-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF

ATOMIC_POSITIONS crystal
    B            0.6666666666       0.3333333333       0.5000000000 
    N            0.3333333333       0.6666666666       0.5000000000 

CELL_PARAMETERS (angstrom)
   2.514856081   0.000000000   0.000000000
  -1.257428041   2.177929253   0.000000000
   0.000000000   0.000000000  10.000000000

K_POINTS automatic
  9 9 1 0 0 0
```

scf for 3 x 3 case:

```
&CONTROL
  calculation = 'scf'
  prefix = 'hbn'
  pseudo_dir = './pseudos/'
  outdir = './out/'
/

&SYSTEM
  ibrav = 0
  nat = 18
  ntyp = 2
  occupations = 'smearing'
  smearing = 'mv'
  degauss =   0.002
  ecutwfc =   60
  ecutrho =   600
/

&ELECTRONS
  mixing_beta =   0.7
  conv_thr =      1d-6
/
ATOMIC_SPECIES
    5      10.811       B.pbe-n-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
    7      14.0067      N.pbe-n-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF

ATOMIC_POSITIONS angstrom
    5    1.2574280400    0.7259764180    5.0000000000
    7    0.0000000000    1.4519528350    5.0000000000
    5   -0.0000000010    2.9039056710    5.0000000000
    7   -1.2574280410    3.6298820880    5.0000000000
    5   -1.2574280420    5.0818349240    5.0000000000
    7   -2.5148560820    5.8078113410    5.0000000000
    5    3.7722841210    0.7259764180    5.0000000000
    7    2.5148560810    1.4519528350    5.0000000000
    5    2.5148560800    2.9039056710    5.0000000000
    7    1.2574280400    3.6298820880    5.0000000000
    5    1.2574280390    5.0818349240    5.0000000000
    7   -0.0000000010    5.8078113410    5.0000000000
    5    6.2871402020    0.7259764180    5.0000000000
    7    5.0297121620    1.4519528350    5.0000000000
    5    5.0297121610    2.9039056710    5.0000000000
    7    3.7722841210    3.6298820880    5.0000000000
    5    3.7722841200    5.0818349240    5.0000000000
    7    2.5148560800    5.8078113410    5.0000000000 

CELL_PARAMETERS (angstrom)
   7.544568243   0.000000000   0.000000000
  -3.772284123   6.533787759   0.000000000
   0.000000000   0.000000000  10.000000000

K_POINTS automatic
  3 3 1 0 0 0
```

scf file for 7 x 7 case:

```
&CONTROL
  calculation = 'scf'
  prefix = 'hbn'
  pseudo_dir = './pseudos/'
  outdir = './out/'
/

&SYSTEM
  ibrav = 0
  nat = 98
  ntyp = 2
  occupations = 'smearing'
  smearing = 'mv'
  degauss =   0.002
  ecutwfc =   60
  ecutrho =   600
/

&ELECTRONS
  mixing_beta =   0.7
  conv_thr =      1d-6
/
ATOMIC_SPECIES
    5      10.811       B.pbe-n-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
    7      14.0067      N.pbe-n-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF

ATOMIC_POSITIONS angstrom
    5    1.2574280400    0.7259764180    5.0000000000
    7    0.0000000000    1.4519528350    5.0000000000
    5   -0.0000000010    2.9039056710    5.0000000000
    7   -1.2574280410    3.6298820880    5.0000000000
    5   -1.2574280420    5.0818349240    5.0000000000
    7   -2.5148560820    5.8078113410    5.0000000000
    5   -2.5148560830    7.2597641770    5.0000000000
    7   -3.7722841230    7.9857405940    5.0000000000
    5   -3.7722841240    9.4376934300    5.0000000000
    7   -5.0297121640   10.1636698470    5.0000000000
    5   -5.0297121650   11.6156226830    5.0000000000
    7   -6.2871402050   12.3415991000    5.0000000000
    5   -6.2871402060   13.7935519360    5.0000000000
    7   -7.5445682460   14.5195283530    5.0000000000
    5    3.7722841210    0.7259764180    5.0000000000
    7    2.5148560810    1.4519528350    5.0000000000
    5    2.5148560800    2.9039056710    5.0000000000
    7    1.2574280400    3.6298820880    5.0000000000
    5    1.2574280390    5.0818349240    5.0000000000
    7   -0.0000000010    5.8078113410    5.0000000000
    5   -0.0000000020    7.2597641770    5.0000000000
    7   -1.2574280420    7.9857405940    5.0000000000
    5   -1.2574280430    9.4376934300    5.0000000000
    7   -2.5148560830   10.1636698470    5.0000000000
    5   -2.5148560840   11.6156226830    5.0000000000
    7   -3.7722841240   12.3415991000    5.0000000000
    5   -3.7722841250   13.7935519360    5.0000000000
    7   -5.0297121650   14.5195283530    5.0000000000
    5    6.2871402020    0.7259764180    5.0000000000
    7    5.0297121620    1.4519528350    5.0000000000
    5    5.0297121610    2.9039056710    5.0000000000
    7    3.7722841210    3.6298820880    5.0000000000
    5    3.7722841200    5.0818349240    5.0000000000
    7    2.5148560800    5.8078113410    5.0000000000
    5    2.5148560790    7.2597641770    5.0000000000
    7    1.2574280390    7.9857405940    5.0000000000
    5    1.2574280380    9.4376934300    5.0000000000
    7   -0.0000000020   10.1636698470    5.0000000000
    5   -0.0000000030   11.6156226830    5.0000000000
    7   -1.2574280430   12.3415991000    5.0000000000
    5   -1.2574280440   13.7935519360    5.0000000000
    7   -2.5148560840   14.5195283530    5.0000000000
    5    8.8019962830    0.7259764180    5.0000000000
    7    7.5445682430    1.4519528350    5.0000000000
    5    7.5445682420    2.9039056710    5.0000000000
    7    6.2871402020    3.6298820880    5.0000000000
    5    6.2871402010    5.0818349240    5.0000000000
    7    5.0297121610    5.8078113410    5.0000000000
    5    5.0297121600    7.2597641770    5.0000000000
    7    3.7722841200    7.9857405940    5.0000000000
    5    3.7722841190    9.4376934300    5.0000000000
    7    2.5148560790   10.1636698470    5.0000000000
    5    2.5148560780   11.6156226830    5.0000000000
    7    1.2574280380   12.3415991000    5.0000000000
    5    1.2574280370   13.7935519360    5.0000000000
    7   -0.0000000030   14.5195283530    5.0000000000
    5   11.3168523640    0.7259764180    5.0000000000
    7   10.0594243240    1.4519528350    5.0000000000
    5   10.0594243230    2.9039056710    5.0000000000
    7    8.8019962830    3.6298820880    5.0000000000
    5    8.8019962820    5.0818349240    5.0000000000
    7    7.5445682420    5.8078113410    5.0000000000
    5    7.5445682410    7.2597641770    5.0000000000
    7    6.2871402010    7.9857405940    5.0000000000
    5    6.2871402000    9.4376934300    5.0000000000
    7    5.0297121600   10.1636698470    5.0000000000
    5    5.0297121590   11.6156226830    5.0000000000
    7    3.7722841190   12.3415991000    5.0000000000
    5    3.7722841180   13.7935519360    5.0000000000
    7    2.5148560780   14.5195283530    5.0000000000
    5   13.8317084450    0.7259764180    5.0000000000
    7   12.5742804050    1.4519528350    5.0000000000
    5   12.5742804040    2.9039056710    5.0000000000
    7   11.3168523640    3.6298820880    5.0000000000
    5   11.3168523630    5.0818349240    5.0000000000
    7   10.0594243230    5.8078113410    5.0000000000
    5   10.0594243220    7.2597641770    5.0000000000
    7    8.8019962820    7.9857405940    5.0000000000
    5    8.8019962810    9.4376934300    5.0000000000
    7    7.5445682410   10.1636698470    5.0000000000
    5    7.5445682400   11.6156226830    5.0000000000
    7    6.2871402000   12.3415991000    5.0000000000
    5    6.2871401990   13.7935519360    5.0000000000
    7    5.0297121590   14.5195283530    5.0000000000
    5   16.3465645260    0.7259764180    5.0000000000
    7   15.0891364860    1.4519528350    5.0000000000
    5   15.0891364850    2.9039056710    5.0000000000
    7   13.8317084450    3.6298820880    5.0000000000
    5   13.8317084440    5.0818349240    5.0000000000
    7   12.5742804040    5.8078113410    5.0000000000
    5   12.5742804030    7.2597641770    5.0000000000
    7   11.3168523630    7.9857405940    5.0000000000
    5   11.3168523620    9.4376934300    5.0000000000
    7   10.0594243220   10.1636698470    5.0000000000
    5   10.0594243210   11.6156226830    5.0000000000
    7    8.8019962810   12.3415991000    5.0000000000
    5    8.8019962800   13.7935519360    5.0000000000
    7    7.5445682400   14.5195283530    5.0000000000 

CELL_PARAMETERS (angstrom)
   17.603992567  0.000000000   0.000000000
  -8.801996287   15.245504771  0.000000000
   0.000000000   0.000000000  10.000000000

K_POINTS automatic
  3 3 1 0 0 0
```

Comment: +1 and welcome to MMSE!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the size of the supercell increases, you can reduce the number of k-points in an inverse manner to get the same accuracy as the one with the smaller cell. This is because the relation between real space and k-space is reciprocal.

For a unit (i.e. $1\times1\times1$) cell, you used $9\times9\times1$ k-grid. So for a $3\times3\times1$ supercell, your new k-point should be $3\times3\times1$ which you correctly used. However, for a $7\times7\times1$ supercell, you still used the same k-grid of $3\times3\times1$ and this increased the k-point density than you had in your previous calculations. That's a probable cause of the noise you see in your DOS.

Moreover, it is not clear if you used the same k-grid in your NSCF calculation or if you increased it a little bit with `occupations='tetrahedra'`. The k-grid of NSCF can decide the DOS output significantly. So my suggestions would be to fix the k-point scaling, and if there is nothing special with a $7\times7\times1$ supercell, then use a supercell where you can calculate the scaling to be an integer. And also check the following suggested k-points distance information from [MaterialsCloud's QE input generator](https://www.materialscloud.org/work/tools/qeinputgenerator). I think for a little bit larger supercell, a `gamma-only` or Baldereschi point-only `1/4 1/4 1/4 (crystal)` sampling will suffice in your case.

> The default is 0.2 1/Å, that is a conservative, all-purpose choice. We call this "fine" sampling, and the appropriate smearing/degauss is 0.2 eV. The two other options are "very fine" sampling (0.15 1/Å, 0.1 eV), or "normal" (0.3 1/Å, 0.3 eV). Note that we change the degauss since a coarser sampling benefits from more smearing. Last: there is no point in sampling the Brillouin Zone in a direction in which there shouldn't be any dispersion (as is the case for, say, a 0-, 1- or 2-dimensional system where 3, 2, or 1 directions shouldn't be sampled); in these cases you should update the input file by hand a posteriori. You can also decide to use a shifted Monkhorst-Pack mesh (just change 0 0 0 -> 1 1 1 in the last 3 numbers of the k-point entry). If you are a PWscf Jedi, for large cells you could use the Baldereschi point (1/4 1/4 1/4) and nosym=.true. to get much better sampling than Gamma-only (at twice the cost).

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answer! For the NSCF calculations, I used a K-POINT grid which is 4 times as dense (e.g. 12 12 1, if for scf it is 3 3 1). I have also used tetrahedra occupations in NSCF. How would I ensure that my k-point scaling is fixed? It is not easy to divide 9 by other integers (apart from 3).

Comment: About the scaling, you can definitely use a gamma-point only (1 1 1) sampling for a 9 9 1 supercell. You can try a gamma point only, or a 2 2 1 sampling in your 7 7 1 supercell maybe but I am not fully sure it would give you identical results but pretty sure it would be better. But for NSCF, 4 times dense k-mesh looks like an overkill. Sometimes when the supercell is large enough (more than 10 Angstrom or so), I don't even change the k-grid in NSCF at all. It still gives me very good DOS output.

Comment: Thanks Abdul! I will try this out and let you know of the result.